# Why elasticsearch request cache not working?

Tags: elasticsearch, caching, request

only 20% queries use request cache, after set request_cache=true for every request, use:

> searchRequest.requestCache(true)

why not all queries use cache?

I found Request cache should work or not depends on IndicesService.canCache method :

1. not use scroll, searchType == QUERY_THEN_FETCH, not use profile : all these should be ok for my request
2. it not use cache when context.getQueryShardContext().isCacheable() == false, the comment on these code is :

> if now in millis is used (or in the future, a more generic "isDeterministic" flag; then we can't cache based on "now" key within the search request, as it is not deterministic

what does this mean?

Thanks

Comment: It means that if your query contains dynamic parts (scripting, date < `now`, etc) the query results cannot be cached

Comment: yes, thanks a lot